# How to remove a specific space using regular expressions.

Tags: python, regex

I have the following bit of code:

```
import re

s = 'The quic k brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.'
pattern = re.compile(r'(\sk\s)')
s = re.sub(pattern, 'k ', s)
```

I want 's' to have a final result of "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. However, the final string result remains unchanged.

What should I change?

Comment: Works perfectly on my machine. Could not reproduce.

Comment: Also, any reason why you don't just do `s = s.replace(' k ', 'k ')`?

Comment: works on python 3, but not on my python 2.7.7 (i should update, i know)

Comment: Works perfectly on my machine with 2.7.9 (above was 3.4.2). Could not reproduce. Is there that much incompatibility between 2.7.7 and 2.7.9?

Comment: why did you compile the pattern and not just `pattern.sub('k ', s)`?

Comment: Works on 2.7.6 and 2.5.2. According to the docs, there shouldn't be any reason for this to behave different on versions > 2.0

Comment: What is you replace `pattern = re.compile(r'(\sk\s)')` with `pattern = 
r'\sk\s'`? [It works on Python 2.7](http://ideone.com/GmFiWp). Note that *pattern* should in fact be a string in `re.sub`, although it works for me with a compiled regex object, too.

Comment: @stribizhev There shouldn't be any difference between passing a string or a `RegexObject`, because `re.sub` will [just convert the string to a `RegexObject` anyway.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub)

Answer (score 1):

When you compile a regex object, you are most likely to use it instead of "static" *re* methods.

Thus, in your case, you will use [`sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.sub) of the compiled regex object:

```
s = 'The quic k brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.'
pattern = re.compile(r'\sk\s')
s = pattern.sub('k ', s)
print s
```

See [demo](http://ideone.com/w2vF9l)

Output: `The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.`

Else, just replace your *pattern* declaration to

```
pattern = r'\sk\s'
```

Note the parentheses are redundant here, you are not using the captured group text.

Also, if there are any hard spaces in the input string, you might want to replace them with normal spaces first with

```
s = s.replace(u'\xa0', u' ')
```

[Another sample code](http://ideone.com/cVTQyw):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re

s = u'The quic k brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.'
s = s.replace(u'\xa0', u' ')
pattern = re.compile(ur'\sk\s')
s = pattern.sub(u'k ', s)
print s
```

Comment: That works just as well as the OP's code for me. I don't know what's going on.